How to avoid "UserWarning: Reading `.npy` or `.npz` file required additional header parsing..."
I'm creating .npz files in Python 2 (yes, Python 2, not 3 and I can't change it) full of .npy files. When reading those .npz files, I'm having the warning message: "UserWarning: Reading .npy or .npz file required additional header parsing as it was created on Python 2. Save the file again to speed up loading and avoid this warning.". Is there any way for me to generate the npz/npy files such that I don't need additional header parsing?
Here is how I proceed to export arrays:
import io
import numpy as np   

array = [1,2,3]
with zipfile.ZipFile("myFile.npz", 'w', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED, allowZip64 = True) as zipf:
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    np.lib.npyio.format.write_array(buf, np.array(array))
    zipf.writestr("myFile.npy", buf.getvalue())


I've found out what's wrong. Actually, in Python 2, the shape is written like (3L,) while it is like (3,) in Python 3. So basically, my solution is to write the .npy myself, correcting the shape in the header. Here is the minimal code:
import io
import numpy as np   

array = [1,2,3]
with zipfile.ZipFile("myFile.npz", 'w', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED, allowZip64 = True) as zipf:
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    arr = np.array(array)

    header_data = {
        'descr': np.lib.npyio.format.dtype_to_descr(arr.dtype),
        'fortran_order': False,
        'shape': tuple(int(dim) for dim in arr.shape), # This is the part that needed the correction
    }

    np.lib.npyio.format.write_array_header_2_0(buf, header_data)
    buf.write(arr.tobytes())

    zipf.writestr("myFile.npy", buf.getvalue())

